# Speakers wont work till i plug in head phones then BOTH head phones and speakers work 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, headphones, speakers

I recently installed 20.04 and my speakers don't work (common issue), but when I plug in my headphones I get audio from both the headphones and the speakers. I've tried a couple  of "fixes" and nothing seems to work. Please help.

Dell Inspiron 5400 AIO

I used alsamixer to set the "auto" feature on, and this works as a bandaid, but not as a fix.

I also tried pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload to no avail.

Comment: I edited it sorry

Comment: Best if you outlined what "fixes" you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

or

`sudo pico /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Find the line that contains `options snd-hda-intel model=`

Change it to `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi`

Reboot

Set sound output in Settings/Sound

Retest

Comment: Nothing appears in the file and when i exit the text editer i get this 

:: (gedit:12191): Tepl-WARNING **: 17:33:42.663: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.::

Comment: This did not work tho now my speakers come on at boot it seems like

Comment: @RobertRichardson  So, after setting the Setting/Sound output to the desired internal speakers, are you saying that it's working now, after a reboot? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/modprobe.d/alsa*` and `grep -i snd-hda-intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`.

Comment: @RobertRichardson Notice how I said "Edit **your** question..."... never modify an existing answer when that information should be put into your original question, and then notify the requester with a comment that starts with "@heynnema". Anyway, lesson aside, you didn't do the mod correctly. Please re-read my answer, make the correct edits, reboot and retest. Report back.

Comment: @RobertRichardson Please see my answer. If it solves the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: sorry im new here ill try again and report back.

Comment: @RobertRichardson Status please...

Comment: @RobertRichardson Status please...